# Storing a Json value Security Threads using wordpress plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security, xss, owasp

I'm performing an audit against OASP best practices, my goal is to identify all major security threads happening when I send the data from the frontend until it is saved in the database.

Context.

Json Data: It's a tree that grows/decreases according to the UI action, the JSON is formatting for a frontend function.

Frontend: custom UI, it generates a list of team members in a JS object and appends/removes from it, the data input is not stored in any HTML elements to prevent XSS, however not sure if there is any potential XSS in the code:

Function to create the element:

```
const newTeam = {
        name,
        emoji,
        parent_id: parentTeamId,
        children: [],
    };

    const newTree = insertTeam( newTeam );
```

Function to add the element to the nested groups:

```
export function insertTeam( team, root = tree ) {
    if ( root.id === team.parent_id ) {
        return {
            ...root,
            children: [
                ...root.children,
                {
                    ...team,
                    // Using a simple time based ID for now.
                    id: `${ root.id }-${ Date.now() }`,
                },
            ],
        };
    }
    return {
        ...root,
        children: root.children.map( ( childTree ) =>
            insertTeam( team, childTree )
        ),
    };
}
```

the data is stored in a hidden field in a form, the final format looks like this:

- Var_Dump

```
string(756) "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"MyCustomGroup.\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":null,\"children\":[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Food\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":1,\"children\":[]},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Canine Therapy\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":1,\"children\":[{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Games\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":3,\"children\":[{\"name\":\"rocket\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":5,\"id\":\"5-1632455609334\",\"children\":[]}]}]},{\"name\":\"frog\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":1,\"id\":\"1-1632456503102\",\"children\":[]},{\"name\":\"bear\",\"emoji\":\"\",\"parent_id\":1,\"id\":\"1-1632456578430\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"a\",\"emoji\":\"a\",\"parent_id\":\"1-1632456578430\",\"children\":[],\"id\":\"1-1632456578430-1632665530415\"}]}]}"
```

The backend: The backend is a Wordpress plugin, to insert the data I'm using `$wpdb->insert` process the string passed and for cleanup / sanitize I'm using:

```
 wp_kses( $obj, array() )
```

I'm not an expert in security, but I can detect threads for XSS attacks, what else I'm missing? Also if you guys have some recommendations are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OWASP security standards, as its name suggests, are only a compilation of standards security checks for web applications. In fact, the npm audit command check for outdated dependencies or known issues. That command doesn't accomplish an audit on the fly. Security issues are raised from several sources, like Node

I think you should try something like [sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)

it's a great test tool and you can start from there